# Content Security Policy blocking CDN

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cdn, content-security-policy

I am new at coding and I working on making a website using bootstrap framework now I use the bootstrap cdn's for javascript and css but once I put the website on a server it blocks the external links. I tried to insert the cdn's into a meta tag as follows:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 
     http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css 
     http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

but once put on the server the browser still blocks the scripts.
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I would like to deal with Content Security Policy inside a hypertext file if possible.

Comment: Are you accessing the web in a intranet?

Comment: I'm putting the website on my University HTTPS server through winSCP

Comment: it uses public IP/DNS

Comment: I'm having no problem using that meta tag and loading bootstrap from the cdn on my local server. Except that it complains for the lack of jquery. What error are you getting on the console of your browser?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem The CDN files use HTTP protocol while the server is a HTTPS server. The console says:  Mixed content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880501/content-security-policy-blocking-cdn#comment67052267_39880501):

> I think I figured out the problem The CDN files use HTTP protocol while the server is a HTTPS server. The console says: Mixed content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Then request and whitelist from https:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 
 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css 
 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```